# Adapting a table to be responsive

Tags: html, css, media-queries, responsive

I am working on a very simple project for freeCodeCamp. I have a table on the site but am having issues getting it to adapt to mobile devices. I have used a media query to try and change its appearence for 400px or less to no avail.

You can see the whole project [here](https://codepen.io/carlosdevelopmentpath/pen/WNwMjjp).

But my question is, why does my table not adapt when using this snippet? As far as I understand it should be no wider than 400px.

```
@media (max-width: 400px){/*Trying to adapt to mobile*/
  #tribute-info table{
    display: fixed;
    max-width: 400px;
    height: auto;
    margin: auto;
  }
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre] here on Stack Overflow, not only on an external site. You can use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) (icon looks like `<>` in the editor toolbar) to do so. Note that it doesn't matter what you set as `max-width` if the content of the columns combined is more than that, and you haven't made allowances for that, it's going to be wider.

Comment: `display:fixed` does not exist but `table-layout:fixed` yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is: Your table content exceeds 400px, so the browser can't cap the table at 400px max-size. If you set the font-size to 2px on your table-content, you'll see it works just fine.

Comment: Absolutely correct. Although I didnt use fontsize to adapt the size, i got rid of some padding and margins and that did the trick!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting your table in a div with class responsive. So your CSS styles as per below. You can change the media query to 400px if you want but i think a min of 520 will be better. Also see screen in media query

```
.table-responsive {
    min-height: .01%;
    overflow-x: auto;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
.table-responsive {
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    -ms-overflow-style: -ms-autohiding-scrollbar;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
.table-responsive > .table {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

Then remember to put your table in a div as per below.

```
    <!-- Don't forget to wrap you table inside a div with the table-responsive class -->
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table>
      .....
    </table>
</div>
```